# Create form HTML for my PHP ADODB

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, adodb

I have a PHP file that takes me in a table my results. 
 Using PHP, I added some filters. I wish I could enter the filter with search form and not through code. 
And, how can I make that happen in a 'static' page (no refresh or change address)?

**index.html** (`<form>` code). For the information, I used JQuery style.
 
[image: Screen]

```
<h1>Ricerca Ordini</h1>
<form action="index.php" method="post"> 
<input type="text" name="input" placeholder="Ricerca Ordini"> <br><br>
<label for="selectmenu">Tipo:</label>
<select id="selectmenu">
    <option>C1</option>
    <option>CR</option>
    <option>F1</option>
    <option>FP</option>
    <option>FPE</option>
    <option selected="selected">All Type</option>
</select>
<label for="spinner">ID:</label>
<input id="spinner"> <br><br>
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to"> <br><br>
<input type="submit" name="search">
</form>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

define ('DBNAME',"./DinamicoWeb.mdb"); // Definisce il nome del database
define ('DBTBL',"Ordini"); // Definisce il nome della tabella
define ('PKNAME',"Id Ord"); // Definisce il nome della chiave primaria
define ('PKCOL',0); // Definisce la posizione della chiave primaria
define ('LINKPK',true); // Abilita i link alla PK per modifica-cancella

$con = new COM("ADODB.Connection");
$conStr = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=".
            realpath(DBNAME).";";
$con->open($conStr);

$id="1";
$tipo="";
$numero="2";
$data1="";
$data2="";
$input="TT";


$sql="SELECT [Id Ord] AS [ID], [Tipo Ord] AS [Tipo], [N Ord] AS [Numero], [Data Ord] AS [Data], [Ragione Sociale], [Indirizzo], [TotImp] AS [IMPORTO TOTALE], [TotIva] AS [IMPORTO IVA] FROM [Ordini] WHERE [Indirizzo] LIKE '%$input%' OR [Ragione Sociale] LIKE '%$input%' OR [Id Ord] LIKE '$id' OR [Tipo Ord] LIKE '$tipo' OR [N Ord] LIKE '$numero'";

$rs = $con->execute($sql);


if($rs === false) {
  trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $con->ErrorMsg(), E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
  $rows_returned = $rs->RecordCount();
}

$numFields = $rs->Fields->count;

// Print HTML
echo '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">';
echo '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">';
echo '<head>';
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" 
     content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />';
echo '<title>Gestione degli '.DBTBL.'</title>';
echo '<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/footable.bootstrap.css">';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/footable.bootstrap.min.css">';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/footable.core.bootstrap.min.css">';
echo '</head><body>';
echo '<h1>GESTIONE '.DBTBL.'</h1>';
// Elenca records -----
//echo ("<div class='table-responsive'>");
echo ("<table class='datatable table tabella_reponsive ui-responsive' summary='Prova dati con MS Access'>");
echo("<caption>Tabella ".DBTBL."</caption>\n");
echo("<thead><tr>\n");
for ($i=0;$i<$numFields;$i++){
    echo("<th scope='col'>");
    echo $rs->Fields($i)->name;
    echo("</th>\n");
}
echo("</tr></thead>\n");
echo("<tbody>");

$alt = false;
while (!$rs->EOF)
{
    echo("<tr>");
    for ($i=0;$i<$numFields;$i++){
      $altClass = $alt ? " class='alt'" : "";
      if (LINKPK && $i==PKCOL){
        echo "<td".$altClass."><a href='?id=".$rs->Fields($i)->value
              ."'>".$rs->Fields($i)->value."</a></td>\n";
      }
      else{
        echo "<td".$altClass.">".$rs->Fields($i)->value."</td>\n";
      }
    }
    echo("</tr>\n");    
    $rs->MoveNext();
    $alt = !$alt;
}
echo("</tbody>");
echo("</table>\n");
echo("</div>");
echo '</body></html>';
$rs->Close();
$con->Close();
?>
```

I used these variables to make the test, and it works correctly.

> $id="1"; 
>  
>     $tipo=""; 
>  
>     $numero="2"; 
>  
>     $data1=""; 
>  
>     $data2=""; 
>  
>     $input="TT";

[image: Result]

**Insert snippet:** (index.html)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ricerca Ordini</title>
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
      from = $( "#from" )
        .datepicker({
          defaultDate: "+1w",
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          numberOfMonths: 1
        })
        .on( "change", function() {
          to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
        }),
      to = $( "#to" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1
      })
      .on( "change", function() {
        from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
      });
 
    function getDate( element ) {
      var date;
      try {
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
      } catch( error ) {
        date = null;
      }
 
      return date;
    }
  } );
  </script>
 <style>
 body{
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  margin: 50px;
 }
 .demoHeaders {
  margin-top: 2em;
 }
 #dialog-link {
  padding: .4em 1em .4em 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
 }
 #dialog-link span.ui-icon {
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: .2em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -8px;
 }
 #icons {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 #icons li {
  margin: 2px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 4px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
 }
 #icons span.ui-icon {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 4px;
 }
 .fakewindowcontain .ui-widget-overlay {
  position: absolute;
 }
 select {
  width: 200px;
 }
 </style>
 
</head>

<body>
<h1>Ricerca Ordini</h1>
<form action="index.php" method="post"> 
<input type="text" name="input" placeholder="Ricerca Ordini"> <br><br>
<label for="selectmenu">Tipo:</label>
<select id="selectmenu">
 <option>C1</option>
 <option>CR</option>
 <option>F1</option>
 <option>FP</option>
 <option>FPE</option>
 <option selected="selected">All Type</option>
</select> 
<label for="spinner">ID:</label>
<input id="spinner"> <br><br>
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to"> <br><br>
<input type="submit" name="search">
</form>

<script src="external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>

$( "#accordion" ).accordion();



var availableTags = [
 "ActionScript",
 "AppleScript",
 "Asp",
 "BASIC",
 "C",
 "C++",
 "Clojure",
 "COBOL",
 "ColdFusion",
 "Erlang",
 "Fortran",
 "Groovy",
 "Haskell",
 "Java",
 "JavaScript",
 "Lisp",
 "Perl",
 "PHP",
 "Python",
 "Ruby",
 "Scala",
 "Scheme"
];
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
 source: availableTags
});



$( "#button" ).button();
$( "#button-icon" ).button({
 icon: "ui-icon-gear",
 showLabel: false
});



$( "#radioset" ).buttonset();



$( "#controlgroup" ).controlgroup();



$( "#tabs" ).tabs();



$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
 autoOpen: false,
 width: 400,
 buttons: [
  {
   text: "Ok",
   click: function() {
    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
   }
  },
  {
   text: "Cancel",
   click: function() {
    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
   }
  }
 ]
});

// Link to open the dialog
$( "#dialog-link" ).click(function( event ) {
 $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
 event.preventDefault();
});



$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
 inline: true
});



$( "#slider" ).slider({
 range: true,
 values: [ 17, 67 ]
});



$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
 value: 20
});



$( "#spinner" ).spinner();



$( "#menu" ).menu();



$( "#tooltip" ).tooltip();



$( "#selectmenu" ).selectmenu();


// Hover states on the static widgets
$( "#dialog-link, #icons li" ).hover(
 function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-hover" );
 },
 function() {
  $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-hover" );
 }
);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add on your index.php this:

```
$input=$_POST['input'];
$id=$_POST['id'];
$tipo=$_POST['tipo'];
$numero=$_POST['numero'];
```

And change your index.html:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post"> 
<input type="text" name="input" placeholder="Ricerca Ordini"> <br><br>
<label for="selectmenu">Tipo:</label>
<select id="selectmenu" name="tipo">
    <option>C1</option>
    <option>CR</option>
    <option>F1</option>
    <option>FP</option>
    <option>FPE</option>
    <option selected="selected">All Type</option>
</select>
<label for="spinner">ID:</label>
<input id="spinner" name="id"> <br><br>
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to"> <br><br>
<input type="submit" name="search">
</form>
```

The filed "name" on html must be the same of ['name'] on php.

Comment: Thanks! This code work perfeclty. But if i leave "input" text empty and select "tipo" on combobox, on php show me ALL result and not only with my "Tipo" selected.